# Java servlet - Log version of TLS that's being used in a secure connection from code?

Tags: java, ssl

I'd like to log the TLS version that's being used when my web app receives requests, and when it does server side HTTP requests.

I've tried enabling TLS logging at the VM level, but it's much too verbose for my liking, and I'd like to just log it at a few points in my app.

How can I do this?

Comment: It isn't available via the Servlet API.

Comment: What server are you using ? Tomcat ? JBOSS ?

Comment: We have lots of different server use cases where I work.... Jetty and Tomcat are 2 that I personally have worked with here, so any suggestions there would be good... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my situation, I could never figure this out, as there was a load balancer in front of my app, and the load balancer had the SSL cert installed on it, not my nodes.

My company uses "SSL termination", which means that the SSL connection ends at the load balancer - so no nodes in our app are ever served securely (they're on an internal network of course, which is only available to the load balancer).

So if you're looking into this, first find out if your load balancer is working in this way, because if it is, you won't get any SSL info in your requests at all no matter what!

Comment: Actually maybe you could... For example, Apache's mod_ssl can forward any of its original, SSL/TLS enabled request details in headers it creates. e.g. `Header set X-SSL-PROTOCOL "expr=%{SSL_PROTOCOL}"`. What is hard is having a single code base that works wether or not you are using SSL termination, in production as well as other dev / test / integration platforms, and also on direct Servlet Container access :-).

Comment: @GPI - yeah good point - We have lots of different servers, but mostly use haproxy as the load balancer, and have decided to log it there instead, as we really don't want to modify any code if possible, since we have lots of different apps/code bases.